# Bisection Method Implementation

Tags: c

I'm working on a program to program the bisection method:
https://www.calculushowto.com/bisection-method/

I know there's questions similar to this one but I want to see if my own one works.

```
double func(double x) {
    return x * x - 3 * x - 1;
}
    
double bisect(double (*f)(double), double a, double b, double e) {
    double mid = (a + b) / 2;
    while (abs(mid) > e) {
        if (f(mid) < 0) {
            mid = a;
        } else {
            mid = b;
        }
    }
      
    return mid;       
}
```

`func()` is the function I'm using to test the bisection method. In the other function, `a` is the left point, `b` is the right point and `e` is the error bound.

Any mistakes that I didn't catch?

Answer (score 1):

- You seem to assume that there is a root between `a` and `b`. If it is not the case, `bisect` will never terminate. Assuming that `f` is well-behaving, it would be prudent to test that `f(a)` and `f(b)` have different signs before proceeding.

  Also, consider the case `f(a) > 0 && f(b) < 0`
- `bisect` doesn't find the approximation of the root. It finds an argument at which `f` is reasonably small. It could be quite far from the root. A prudent termination condition is `b - a < e`.
- `a + b` may overflow, and then all bets are off. Consider `mid = a + (b - a)/2`.

Comment: `a` and `b` are floating-point numbers, which makes the overflow less likely.  But does mean we ought to be checking for non-finite values (infinities and NANs) before we do *any* arithmetic.

Comment: "bisect will never terminate." --> Likely the integer truncation of `abs(mid)` will readily  cause the loop to quit.

Comment: Given `a,b` are unordered, `b - a` can overflow like `a + b`.  Alternate `a/2 + b/2;`

Answer (score 0):

> Any mistakes that I didn't catch?

**Bug: wrong function**

`abs()` is for `int`.  Use `fabs()`.  `abs(mid)` is a problem when `mid` out of `int` range  and not mathematical the desired algorithm as it truncates.  Slower to converting to and from `int` too.

```
double mid = (a + b) / 2;
// while (abs(mid) > e) {
while (fabs(mid) > e) {
```

---

**Subtle**

`(x - 3)*x - 1;` is more computational stable than `x * x - 3 * x - 1`.